# how can I return values of any type in C?

Tags: c, void-pointers

i need get some logs from uses of variables in C code;

For example from the following code:

```
int main(){
   int a,b,c;
   a=1;
   b=1;
   c= a==0||b==1
   return 0;
}
```

i make:

```
int log(int v){
   //print log
   return v;
}

int main(){
   int a,b,c;
   a=1;
   b=1;
   c= log(a)==0||log(b)==1
   return 0;
}
```

this work perfectly, but with all variables int.

how can i do this for variable of any type?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It would really help if instead of a comment, you showed an example of what the actual logging might look like. It's hard to see how the path you've started down could ever produce sensible logs and so this is probably an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I think you want to run your program in a debugger and use watchpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG(TYPE, STRING, VAR) \
 (printf(STRING, VAR), (TYPE) VAR)

int main()
{
    int j = 3;
    double q = 2.3;
    double s;

    s = LOG(int, "j=%d\n", j) + LOG(double, "q=%lf\n", q);
    LOG(double, "s=%lf\n", s);
}
```

> j=3
>   q=2.300000
>   s=5.300000

One caution: This evaluates the `VAR` expression twice, so it should always be the contents of a regular variable, not a more complex expression. You can replace the call to `printf` with a call to a logging operation that uses varargs.

Answer (score 0):

[Log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/) is your friend:

> Log4c is a library of C for flexible logging to files, syslog and other destinations. It is modeled after the Log for Java library (http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/), staying as close to their API as is reasonable. Here is a short introduction to Log4j which describes the API, and design rationale.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i do this for variable of any type?

To switch code based on various types,  use `_Generic()` to select type specific functions.

```
int log_int(int v) {
  printf("(int %d)\n", v);
  return !!v;
}

int log_double(double v) {
  printf("(double %e)\n", v);
  return !!v;
}

int log_char_ptr(char *v) {
  printf("(str %s)\n", v);
  return !!v;
}

#define mylog(X) _Generic((X), \
  int: log_int, \
  double: log_double, \
  char *: log_char_ptr \
  )(X)
```

Now code only needs to call `mylog(various_types)`.

```
int main(void) {
  int i = 3;
  double d = 4.0;
  char *s = "5";

  mylog(i)==0||mylog(d)==0||mylog(s)==0;
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
(int 3)
(double 4.000000e+00)
(str 5)
```